# Java problem, disabled controls still fires events!

Tags: java, swing

I'm new to Java, I'm coding on NetBeans. The problem is that whenever I disable a control
i.e jmenu.setEnabled(false) it still fires events! holy crap! how is it! :P

How can I prevent it?

Comment: "something"? and what controls?

Comment: any control i have used so far like jmenu , jbutton

Comment: which events? can you post some more code?

Comment: mouseclicked to be specific is the problem, control still fires in disabled state,and i just tie the code from the ide automatically, it looks like any other event,nothing weird

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fit in with the event model adopted by Swing, I think your best option is to just add a check of isEnabled() in the handlers that you don't want executed when the component is disabled.

Comment: yea , thought that too;took me a while.programming in c# has got me lazy in low level stuff

Answer (score 7):

From the [javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setEnabled(boolean)):

> Note: Disabling a lightweight
>   component does not prevent it from
>   receiving MouseEvents.
>
> Note: Disabling a heavyweight
>   container prevents all components in
>   this container from receiving any
>   input events. But disabling a
>   lightweight container affects only
>   this container.

You might want to check out [disableEvents(long mask)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#disableEvents(long)).

Comment: thank you, but then, what can i do to prevent the lightweight componenet of receiving event calls in disabled state and still allow the heavyweight container to receive the calls?

Answer (score 1):

Consider using `javax.swing.Action`-controlled Swing components.

In this way, you can instead disable an Action directly with `Action.setEnabled`. Its component(s) will adopt its state automatically. When disabled in this manner, the components won't receive MouseEvents.

See the docs on the constructor `JButton(Action)`.